# Can we have more than 1 CSV file in a Jmeter Sampler?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

Is it possible to have more than one CSV file for a Single sampler?
I mean, I want to read values from a text file & a CSV file simultaneously for a single JMS request.
Could it be possible?

Answer (score 1):

Well, simply add one more [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to read values from another csv-file (if you use this component to read from csv) or use several calls of [__StringFromFile](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) function (or even 1 call to read from several files).

Your schema may look like:

```
...
CSV Data Set Config
  Filename: list_A.csv
  Variable Names: paramA1,paramA2,...
CSV Data Set Config
  Filename: list_B.csv
  Variable Names: paramB1,paramB2,...
JMS Sampler
  // use here params from both csv-files as ${paramA1},${paramB1},...
...
```

Comment: Hey Alies thanks for your reply. I have a payload(xml) file in which I have to make certain values dynamic, that keep changing for every request. Those values have to be picked up from a CSV file. Now, if it was a Http request that could have been easily achieved. But, since this is a JMS sampler I am not sure of how to do it. Your inputs??

Comment: Well. Can you possibly better describe your scenario and desired result? Which JMS sampler are you using? From [jmeter-plugins one](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/JMSSampler)? If so, there is in it possibility to send xml along with. If you are using e.g. [JMS Publisher](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Publisher) and want send along with it xml fitted with values form CSVs so you possibly have to rewrite your xml using e.g. Beanshell / BSF / JSR223 Sampler/PreProcessor/PostProcessor (with corresponding script) called in your script before JMS.